# Can we create our own theme's function.php?

Tags: functions, theme-development

I created my own theme in WordPress and include all the related files. But when I paste the `functions.php` file from other theme, my page started giving below errors-

```
Warning: require(D:\Arisen\xampp\htdocs\test/wp-content/themes/luco_watch/inc/custom-header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\Arisen\xampp\htdocs\test\wp-content\themes\luco_watch\functions.php on line 354

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'D:\Arisen\xampp\htdocs\test/wp-content/themes/luco_watch/inc/custom-header.php' (include_path='D:\Arisen\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\Arisen\xampp\htdocs\test\wp-content\themes\luco_watch\functions.php on line 354
```

And as I remove that `functions.php` file, my site is going good.

So my question is, Can we create our own `functions.php` file and how?
I need that file otherwise I am not gonna include that file.

Answer (score 2):

You can, and should, make your own functions.php file.

You can't drop a whole chunk of code that depends on other files into your theme and just expect it to work.  It probably also contains a load of things you don't need.

Start with an empty `functions.php` and just add things as you need them.  Have a look at the sorts of functions used in one of the themes by wordpress.org or Automattic as a good starting point, as they tend to be pretty clean compared to some other themes and also try to showcase the newest theme features.  Twenty Sixteen maybe.

Comment: Actually I am not using function.php in my theme but now I am using woocommerce plugin, so for that I have to write some code in function.php.

Comment: Can it possible that if I would write only those code in function.php?